# Not able to login to drupal

Tags: drupal

With the intention to disable login page from the home page on drupal I accidentally disabled the entire login.

Could some one help in me restoring that or reset the settings.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't disable the login.. But you just remove it as a block. Go to "yoursite.com/user" and you can login.

Comment: I did try loging on to "mysite.com/admin" that give me and error called access denied.

Comment: yes. if you are not login you can't access the admin page. What it displays on the /user ?

Comment: I was able to login to /user and after logging into that I was able to login into admin.

Comment: Thanks! And I think is a good way to keep the site secure

Comment: It will not make your site more secure, because everybody knows that. But it's secure anyway.